# Choosing CPU for general use

Tags: processor

We're looking for a notebook for my wife.

She will use it for browsing, editing documents (text and spreadsheet) and watching videos. Nothing hard.

Based on our requirements HP G4 with 128 GB SSD seems to be a good choice.

My only question is now CPU as we can by the same notebook with different CPUs:

- HP 250 G4 with Intel Celeron N3050 for €300
- HP 250 G4 with Intel Pentium N3700 for €360
- HP 250 G4 with Intel Core i3 5005U for €390

(All prices without OS, I'll buy windows 10 separately).

I'm open to pay more if that makes a difference, but not in case if all perform the same for the given use.
Which CPU should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the three notebook options you've provided, I'd personally go with i3 5005u. Using cpuboss.com, it is clear that the i3 has significantly better single core and multi-core performance than the Pentium n3700. You probably won't need the extra performance for web browsing and document editing, but it will come in handy in a situation where a little more processing power is needed. Also in performance, the i3 has a higher integrated gpu perfomance than the Pentium, which should help with improving video playback (1080p @ 60fps) and multi-screen. Furthermore, Intel ark says that the i3 supports 16gb of ram compared to 8gb which the Pentium supports. This gives "upgradability" for the future, just in case.

Hope this was helpful :D

(sources: intel ark, cpu boss)